# iOS/XCode NSURLConnection giving 403 forbidden

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl

I am trying to connect to one of our development server which doesn't have a valid certificate as of now. So basically, I want to bypass certificate validation as of now. 
I already have NSAppTransportSecurity in my info.plist file & have also overriden didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge but no use.

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:testserver.com"]];
[NSURLRequest allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:@"testserver.com" ];
NSMutableURLRequest *mutableReq = [req mutableCopy];
[mutableReq setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[mutableReq setValue:@"Basic someKey" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
  NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:mutableReq delegate:self];
```

didReceiveAuthinticationChallenge is getting called and it looks like this:

```
(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
             [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I am getting 403 forbidden from my server whereas from Android, doing the similar thing, trusting all the certificate works fine.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

NSLog message was like below :

```
Connection failed:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x174649120 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://testserver.com, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://testserver.com _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
```

Comment: Is that just a typo? `[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:testserver.com"]]` should be `[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://testserver.com"]]`

Comment: Use NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection.

Comment: @Flexicoder yeah its a typo, because in code i m using direct IP as https://109.XXX.XXX.XXX

Comment: @GouravJoshi I m new to iOS so please correct me if I am wrong, I thought NSURLSession is more for downloads, back to back requests etc. Here, I am just expecting some JSON result for my request and thats it.

Comment: As I am working in swift and call the API by NSURLSessions, Ok, I see the error, you need to add exception domain in the App Security Transport in pList, then that error will not occured.

Comment: @GouravJoshi that also I tried, I added my domain specifically under AppTransport in pList, that also didn't work.

Comment: I have installed server's certificate also on my test device, still I am getting 403 forbidden :(